# GDB and shared object libraries with SIGILL

Tags: linux, gdb, shared-libraries, shared

I am trying to debug programs on an ARM target device with GDB and GDB seems to be acting odd with regards to ld-linux.so.3. It's a simple program that just printf("Hello World").

Approximately half the time, gdb it will run and the other half jump to this error after typing run:

```
Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x2aab9bc4 in _dl_debug_state () from /lib/ld-linux.so.3
```

I've also tried to statically link the libraries and I still get this error, albeit slightly less, but it still occurs with enough frequency to be problematic.

I set solib-absolute-prefix to /dev/null and solib-search-path to /lib/ on the target and it loads up the ld-linux.so.3 fine it says. Is there anything I need to do like recompile the libraries for target again or some flags GDB wants to know?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the program work without GDB?

Comment: Does the target device operate as a _freestanding_ or _hosted_ environment?  See sections 1.4 and 17.6.1.3 of [the latest C++ draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3090.pdf) for a description of the two environments.  If you are running in a _freestanding_ environment, then `printf()` might not be available.  Many of the embedded platforms that I have worked on did not provide it.

Comment: You may find problems trying to use gdb locally on embedded systems, if that is your case. Some of these platforms have hardware constraints (short limited memory) that makes debugging a challenge.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if it is a memory problem. cat /proc/meminfo gives me approximately 
MemTotal:         414892 kB
MemFree:          262688 kB

So I don't know if that is a big issue. And yes, the program runs fine in normal execution. I'm pretty much at a loss right now.